# truffle deploy: Network state unknown when geth is synced

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, contract-deployment

```
eth.syncing false eth.blockNumber 5199029
truffle deploy --network=live
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js Deploying Migrations... ... undefined Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually. Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

I understand I need to add funds to my wallet. But why "network state unknown"?

Yes I ran with RPC. I first got an error that the account was locked so I unlocked it.

Reran the truffle deploy `--network=live` command and still got "network state unknown"

```
~/truffle version
Truffle v4.1.3 (core: 4.1.3)
Solidity v0.4.19 (solc-js)
~/geth version
Geth
Version: 1.8.2-stable
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.10
Operating System: darwin
GOPATH=/Users/quantum/code/go
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10/libexec
~/
```

Comment: I think the only problem is that you don't have funds in your wallet. I'd bet that if you added funds this would go away.

Comment: I think you would be right, but when I add the balance: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42068/transaction-not-found-after-50-blocks-on-mainnet happens

Comment: What version of truffle do you use?

Comment: Added to question. I deployed my contract through REMIX, after paying far higher than the "recommended" gas

Answer (score 1):

Possible it's not unlocked long enough?

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.personal.listAccounts[0],"password",15000); // 1st account, pw & time in seconds ...
```

Comment: That's the most reasonable answer yet. I still have this problem: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42068/transaction-not-found-after-50-blocks-on-mainnet but I'm awarding you the bounty for a reasonable answer

Comment: Sweet. Thanks. It's unfortunate the errors can be cryptic and somewhat misleading. It makes us doublecheck all the things we think we know. Funded, unlocked, sufficient funds for eth + gas, constructor can run. Did you check that there is nothing in the constructor that might throw with infinite gas consumption? A `require`?

Comment: Yeah -- I ended up deploying through Metamask + Remix, and offering about quadruple the amount of gas I was. Anything below that was giving me warnings: "want to retry with more gas?"