# Transaction not found after 50 blocks on mainnet

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

I updated geth & truffle today.

Now I'm getting "Transaction not found after 50 blocks" when trying to deploy to mainnet.

I tried setting my gas higher than anything on http://ethgasstation.info/ , still with no publication of the contract.

truffle.js:

```
live: { host: "127.0.0.1", port: 8545, network_id: "*", from: "0xa281cd2ba15dc43f8110ddaee837274800931f7e", gasPrice: 9, gas: 200000 },
```

(I also tried with gasPrice: 1, 2 and 3)

and here's the log from `truffle migrate --network=live --verbose-rpc`

```
"jsonrpc": "2.0",

"id": 5, "method": "eth_sendTransaction", "params": [ { "from": "0xa281cd2ba15dc43f8110ddaee837274800931f7e", "gas": "0x30d40", "gasPrice": "0x204876e800", "data": "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" } ] }


eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])
100000000000000000
```

which is plenty more than gas * gasPrice.

````
/geth version
Geth
Version: 1.8.2-stable
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.10
Operating System: darwin
GOPATH=/Users/quantum/code/go
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10/libexec
~/truffle version
Truffle v4.0.6 (core: 4.0.6)
Solidity v0.4.19 (solc-js)
```

and to the end..

```
  >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "id": 1568,
   >   "method": "eth_uninstallFilter",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0xbe6517333d9e36227699e900b12523bc"
   >   ]
   > }
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/contract.js:112:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/filter.js:128:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/filter.js:127:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.onMessage [as callback] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/filter.js:125:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:259:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:258:10
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-migrate/index.js:225:1
````

EDIT:

Attempted with `7000000000"result", and again with 9GWEI:

"0x8f81a39e5d6b78e93ac23aaf6628d8ea1aa9b4924fd2a6ec1f569083dc0d7abb"
 <   }
  ... 0x8f81a39e5d6b78e93ac23aaf6628d8ea1aa9b4924fd2a6ec1f569083dc0d7abb

```
{
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "id": 5,
   >   "method": "eth_sendTransaction",
   >   "params": [
   >     {
   >       "from": "0xa281cd2ba15dc43f8110ddaee837274800931f7e",
   >       "gas": "0x30d40",
   >       "gasPrice": "0x218711a00",
   >       "data": (all the data)
   >     }
   >   ]
   > }
 <   {
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "id": 5,
 <     "result": "0x8f81a39e5d6b78e93ac23aaf6628d8ea1aa9b4924fd2a6ec1f569083dc0d7abb"
 <   }
  ... 0x8f81a39e5d6b78e93ac23aaf6628d8ea1aa9b4924fd2a6ec1f569083dc0d7abb
   > {
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "id": 6,
   >   "method": "eth_newBlockFilter",
   >   "params": []
   > }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're setting the gas price wrong. You said you tried high gas prices, but it looks like your gas prices are in the single digits.

The gas price is specified in wei. A reasonable gas price right now is about 3 **gwei**. That's 3000000000 wei.

Comment: Hey Smarx, I saw https://hackernoon.com/ether-purchase-power-df40a38c5a2f?gi=1ce02bd086e1 talk about gas prices being in gwei . I'll try reposting with your wei value

Comment: Posted, logs show 0xb2d05e00 (hex value).. awaiting results

Comment: Failed with 4GWEI, too. Same error (can't find within 50 blocks)

Comment: Can you share the transaction hash?

Comment: added to question. 0x8f81a39e5d6b78e93ac23aaf6628d8ea1aa9b4924fd2a6ec1f569083dc0d7abb . it's not showing at Etherscan. I tried with 7000000000, and trying again with 9 GWei

Comment: Interesting. And your setup is a local node running geth connected to some public network? Is it sync'd up to the current block on that network? `eth.blockNumber` in a geth console should tell you what block it's on. Can you make transactions other ways via that node (e.g. via MetaMask connected to localhost)?

Comment: > eth.blockNumber
5216516
> eth.syncing
false

it's just `geth --fast --rpc` .. should be main network. Can metamask deploy contracts?

Comment: That does look current. I'm a bit stumped. I would try doing some other kind of transaction (`eth.sendTransaction` manually via `geth`, some transaction via MetaMask) to see if those work, but I don't have any more guesses as to what's wrong. BTW, the transaction in Truffle's log seems to set a different gas price. I don't personally use Truffle, so I don't know how to interpret the `.js` file and the output.

Comment: Yes, you can deploy through MetaMask. The easiest way is by using Remix. (Paste your code there and deploy.)

Comment: Remix gives me this error: https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/716 :/ So I will try writing the deployment myself for Metamask. I've tried every day since posting to deploy through geth and it fails everytime, even with 9GWEI.

Comment: There's no need to publish your source code to swarm. See https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/19/testing-and-deploying-smart-contracts-with-remix/ for how to deploy with Remix.